# Expanding collapsed code in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut

Instead of going through each (+) sign at the left and clicking them to expand the collapsed code snippets, is there a shortcut or menu item (I couldn't find it, VS has that) to expand all the collapsed code/comments at once?
Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> on the number-pad.

Comment: You can also right click on the line numbers > Folding > Expand All

Comment: I really miss that shortcut on my Mac (MacBook)... Does anyone know an alternative shortcut for the Mac? (Especially for the Navigator/Package Explorer, where it doesn't even work with an external keyboard!)

Comment: @chris_l I can't test this, but most ctrl commands are mapped to the apple key. Quite possibly that's the case here too.

Comment: Thanks guys. I knew there has to be something, just couldn't find it.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can remap just about everything in Eclipse in the Preferences Under "General -> Keys". There's tons of stuff there that does not have a default keybinding but are still useful. Quick example: My install did not have a shortcut for "Close others" in editor-view, which I now use a lot after mapping it. It's also a good way to find commands you're looking for.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Divide on the numpad to collapse them all again =)

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS,  I was using a PHP plugin.  It wasn't enough to change the shortcut for Collapse on Edit Text.

In Eclipse I did these steps:

1. Ctrl-Shift-L ~ open the short cut list
2. Ctrl-Shift-L ~ hit it again to go to the shortcut preferences page
3. Search for "Collapse" shortcut
4. For the option to "Edit Text", I had to change it to Edit PHP
5. Then I set the shortcut to CMD-SHIFT-UP_ARROW

And that worked.  I'm guessing it would be the same for Edit Java vs. Edit Text

Answer (score 0):

You can try ctrl-0 or `Source>Uncollapse code (All)`